# Summing amplifier - output voltage and power supply

Tags: amplifier

I have to solve a problem where a summing amplifier has AC and DC as inputs.
I calculated the output voltage min and max with the formula:

$$
V_{output} = \frac{R_{f}}{R}(V_{1}+V_{2})
$$

So I have values of V=-30 V=+10.

Now, my problem is that the question states that the amplifier is powered by a ±10 volt supply.

Does it mean that my two output voltages can be only V=-10 and V=+10?

Or how do I calculate the fact that the power supply is ±15 volts?

Comment: Please give your AC and DC inputs' amplitude. And your other circuit parameters, such as \$R_{f}\$.

Comment: 2Sin200πt and 1V connected to 10K resistors, Rf is 100K

Comment: will be any change if input voltage is dc for summing amplifier?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an inverting summing amplifier with 10K+10K and Rf 100K, then your signal would be -30V to 10V, except the amplifier will clip the output signal at (well, in reality, before) it hits the supply rails. The amplifier cannot drive its output voltage beyond the rails (how close it can get with any kind of load depends on the type of amplifier).

A fair approximation for your purposes would be that it would be:

Vout = max(\$ -20sin(200\pi t) -10 , -10\$)

In reality it would probably clip a bit before that (so it would also likely clip on the positive peaks) and could (for some op-amps) take a noticeable amount of time (even at 100Hz) to recover from the clipping.

Comment: thanks... I did the same calculation to get -30 and 10. so I don't need to take into count the fact that there is a ±10 volt supply?

Comment: Please read the answer above, I think it answers that question.